# dhclient giving weird address when hostapd and dnsmasq are installed but not running

Tags: dnsmasq, hostapd, dhclient

I'm trying to set up a script so that I can switch between wlan0 being an AP and being a client at certain times, but I hit a snag. Hostapd and dnsmasq both start up fine and appear to work normally, but when I stop them and try to get the interface to work as a client once more by doing `dhclient wlan0` the IP assigned is incorrect. Where the subnet I'm connected to is 192.168.10.0, it connects to 192.168.0.0 and gets 192.168.0.105 every time. Even when I release the lease with `dhclient -r wlan0`, when I empty dhclinet.wlan0.leases, and when I change the physical dongle to a different one of the same model.

My dnsmasq.conf sets the dhcp range to be 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.55, so I don't think I'm getting DHCP from my own dnsmasq (at least not obviously).

If I do `iwconfig wlan0`, it reports that it is connected to the SSID of the AP and seems normal.

If I get dnsmasq and hostapd to not run at start time, everything seems fine and wlan0 can get an IP normally. After I start and stop hostapd and dnsmasq I experience the behavior above.

Comment: I should also mention here that the network is unreachable by ping in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a funny story. We use a TP-Link Wifi Extender and it seems that the default subnet is 192.168.0.0. I strongly suggest people be careful and aware of the trouble these things might cause, especially during debug.